# Angular2 EventEmitter with last value

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, eventemitter

Basically I want to know is there a way to get last value from `EventEmmiter` right after I have subscribed to it?

Why I need this. Imagine a list component that uses two more components: filter and grid. Filter provides `filter` event and grid provides `sorting` event.

In my list component I want to write code like this:

```
        Observable
            .combineLatest(filtering$, sorting$)
            .switchMap(([filter, sorting]) => {
                return this.api.list(filter, sorting);
            })
            ...
```

Very short elegant code. But there are two problems:

1. [`EventEmitter` is not observable](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3045-ward-bell-do-not-expect-eventemitter-to-be-observable-in-angular-2.htm). It is not much of a problem because I can easily wrap it with observable.
2. Call to API will not be performed until every observable fires at least once. This is a real problem.

Currently I am solving it with [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) from RxJs:

> Represents a value that changes over time. Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (or initial) value and all subsequent notifications.

In my filter component I have:

```
class UsersListFilter {
    private filteringSource = new BehaviorSubject<UserFilter>(new UserFilter());
    filtering$ = this.filteringSource.asObservable();

    ...
}
```

And in my list component:

```
class UsersList {
    @ViewChild(UsersListFilter) private filter: UsersListFilter;
    ...

    setupDataReloading() {
        Observable
            .combineLatest(this.filter.filtering$, this.grid.sorting$)
            ...
    }
}
```

As you can see I do not use `EventEmitter` at all. But this solution feels kinda unnatural in Angular2 because I am ignoring standard way of interacting with child component ([`@Output`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)).

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use `@Output` and have a BehaviorSubject in `UsersList` that subscribes to that EventEmitter (observer role) while acting as `filtering$` (observable role)

Comment: Yes, I can wrap `EventEmitter` with `BehaviorSubject` but then I will need to set default value to it. In my opinion it is responsibility of Filter component not UsersList component.

Comment: Then you can have the Filter component emitted the default value at start

Comment: And if I subscribe on it AFTER it emitted then default value is lost forever.

Comment: If you emit in the constructor it will obviously be lost. I guess emitting in ngOnInit would work, else you can try setTimeout(.., 0) in ngOnInit

Comment: Yeah I thought about it. Probably it will work this way, but looks like a race to me: you need to fire an event at right time and subscribe to the event at right time.

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom class instead

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { ObjectUnsubscribedError } from 'rxjs';


export class CustomEventEmitter<T> extends EventEmitter<T> {

    private _value: T;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    get value(): T {
        return this.getValue();
    }

    getValue(): T {
        if (this.hasError) {
            throw this.thrownError;
        } else if (this.closed) {
            throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
        } else {
            return this._value;
        }
    }

    emit(value?: T) {
        super.emit(this._value = value);
    }
}
```